# Why the source code of conjugate in Numpy cannot be found by using the inspect module?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to see the implementation of the `conjugate` function used in `Numpy`. Then I tried the following:

```py
import numpy as np
import inspect
inspect.getsource(np.conjugate)
```

However, I received the following error message stating that `<ufunc 'conjugate'> is not a module, class, method, function, traceback, frame, or code object`. May someone answer why?

```py
In [8]: inspect.getsource(np.conjugate)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-821ecfb71e08> in <module>()
----> 1 inspect.getsource(np.conj)

/Users/duanlx/anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/inspect.pyc in getsource(object)
    699     or code object.  The source code is returned as a single string.  An
    700     IOError is raised if the source code cannot be retrieved."""
--> 701     lines, lnum = getsourcelines(object)
    702     return string.join(lines, '')
    703

/Users/duanlx/anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/inspect.pyc in getsourcelines(object)
    688     original source file the first line of code was found.  An IOError is
    689     raised if the source code cannot be retrieved."""
--> 690     lines, lnum = findsource(object)
    691
    692     if ismodule(object): return lines, 0

/Users/duanlx/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.pyc in findsource(object)
    149     FIXED version with which we monkeypatch the stdlib to work around a bug."""
    150
--> 151     file = getsourcefile(object) or getfile(object)
    152     # If the object is a frame, then trying to get the globals dict from its
    153     # module won't work. Instead, the frame object itself has the globals

/Users/duanlx/anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/inspect.pyc in getsourcefile(object)
    442     Return None if no way can be identified to get the source.
    443     """
--> 444     filename = getfile(object)
    445     if string.lower(filename[-4:]) in ('.pyc', '.pyo'):
    446         filename = filename[:-4] + '.py'

/Users/duanlx/anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/inspect.pyc in getfile(object)
    418         return object.co_filename
    419     raise TypeError('{!r} is not a module, class, method, '
--> 420                     'function, traceback, frame, or code object'.format(object))
    421
    422 ModuleInfo = namedtuple('ModuleInfo', 'name suffix mode module_type')

TypeError: <ufunc 'conjugate'> is not a module, class, method, function, traceback, frame, or code object
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numpy is written in C, for speed. You can only see the source of Python functions.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. May I know how I can find out if a `Numpy` function is written in `C` or not? I found this [list](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/genindex.html) containing all the `Numpy` functions (both in `python` and `C`), but it seems not obvious to tell.

Comment: Pretty much all of Numpy is in C, IIRC. Generally anything where performance is crucial will be in C.

Comment: How to see its source in C then?